# Draw line on cesium map

Tags: angularjs, typescript, cesiumjs

I am trying to draw line on cesium map from a specific point(long,lat) to a specific direction (in degrees) and extend to the end of screen.

Thanks for your help

I tried for hours to use polyline but didn’t succeed and couldn’t draw at all.

Comment: Please share your code attempts.